# Bash text file editing/modifying

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file that I am trying to modify. I am taking the input file that has lines of the form of

```
(y+1/4,-x+1/2,z+3/4)
```

and trying to change it to

```
   0     1     0    -1     0     0     0     0     1    1 / 4    1 / 2    3 / 4
```

I currently can get to this point

```
   0     1     0 1/4    -1     0     0 1/2     0     0     1 3/4
```

using

```
#!bin/bash
filename="227.dat"
sed -i 's/(/  /g' $filename
sed -i 's/)//g' $filename
sed -i 's/,/    /g' $filename
sed -i 's/-x/-1     0     0/g' $filename
sed -i 's/x/ 1     0     0/g' $filename
sed -i 's/-y/ 0    -1     0/g' $filename
sed -i 's/y/ 0     1     0/g' $filename
sed -i 's/-z/ 0     0    -1/g' $filename
sed -i 's/z/ 0     0     1/g' $filename
sed -i '/+/! s/$/    0 \/ 1    0 \/ 1    0 \/ 1/' $filename

while ((i++)); read -r line; do
  if [[ $line == *[+]* ]]
    then
      sed -i 's/+/ /g' $filename
      echo $i
  fi
done < "$filename"
```

The reason for the echo $i was to see that it correctly gives the line number and I thought perhaps I could use it for commands on those specific lines. I am doing this conversion as the code we use in creating crystal structures needs the vector notation with fractions at the end, not the x,y,z notation. I already know this is not the "prettiest" or simplest solution, but I am very new to all of this and it's what I have been able to piece together so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: Each time you run `sed -i` that's really quite expensive (you're starting a new program, having it create a new output file and then renaming that output file over the old one... for every single change, in present formulation). Much better to run *one* `sed` instance that does all your operations in a single pass -- or use [native string manipulation](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) instead of external tools in the first place.

Comment: For instance, if you can write a regex that matches your input stream, you can use `[[ $line =~ $regex ]]` to put the regex's groups into the `BASH_REMATCH` array -- then you just have *one* `echo` command putting those groups into the right order, easy peasy.

Comment: What's *not* easy right now is parsing out exactly how your existing code works, and thus figuring out what the intended relationship between your stated input and your stated output is -- which makes it unnecessarily difficult to write any ground-up reimplementation, however much doing so may be the obvious Right Thing in present circumstances.

Comment: I understand this isn't the best method, but I just need something that works and can worry about optimizing it later. I'm not sure what regex is (as mentioned, I'm VERY new to all of this). As for the input/output relationship, I'm changing x,y,z to 100,010,001 respectively and need to move any added fractions to the end of the line, all with the spacing shown.

Comment: This is your third almost identical question, and I still struggle to understand what you're trying to do. Can you describe the underlying problem? I understand it's something to do with unit vectors. But how does your input map to your expected output?

Comment: Maybe I just can't describe this any other way. x, y & z correspond to a group of three numbers (100, 010 and 001 respectively). The input has x,y & z (with fractions attached) and it needs to be changed to the vectors (in order they appear on the line) and the fractions moved to the end of the line in the order they appear on the line.

Comment: Does the order of the x,y,z replacement values just need to match the order of the fractions, or is the input order significant above and beyond the need for it to be identical? (All that said -- anything essential to writing an answer is supposed to be *part of the question itself*; consider [edit]ing the question, rather than just adding comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

filename="227.dat"

re='[(]y[+]([[:digit:]/]+),-x[+]([[:digit:]/]+),z[+]([[:digit:]/]+)[)]';
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $re ]]; then
        printf '\t%s' \
            0 1 0 \
           -1 0 0 \
            0 0 1 \
            "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" \
            "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" \
            "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}";
        printf '\n';
    else
        echo "ERROR: $line does not match $re" 1>&2;
    fi;
done <"$filename"
```

...given, your input, returns:

```
   0       1       0       -1      0       0       0       0       1       1/4     1/2     3/4
```

...which as far as I can tell is correct.

---

A more complex approach, making unfounded extrapolations (given the lack of detail and exemplars in the question itself), might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while IFS='(),' read -a pieces; do
  declare -A vars=( [x]=1 [y]=1 [z]=1 [x_sigil]='' [y_sigil]='' [z_sigil]='' )
  for piece in "${pieces[@]}"; do
    #                1   2      3   4
    if [[ $piece =~ (-?)([xyz])([+]([[:digit:]/]+))? ]]; then
      if [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[4]} ]]; then                 # only if there *are* digits
        vars[${BASH_REMATCH[2]}]=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}     # ...then store them.
      fi
      vars[${BASH_REMATCH[2]}_sigil]=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} # store - if applicable
    fi
  done
  printf '\t%s' \
    "0"                 "${vars[x_sigil]}1" 0 \
    "${vars[y_sigil]}1" 0                   0 \
    0                   0                   "${vars[z_sigil]}1" \
    "${vars[y]}"        "${vars[x]}"        "${vars[z]}"
  printf '\n'
done
```

Given the sample inputs provided in a comment on this answer, output is:

```
0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   -1  3/4 1/4 1/2
0   1   0   -1  0   0   0   0   1   1/2 3/4 1/4
0   -1  0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1/4 1/2 3/4
0   -1  0   -1  0   0   0   0   -1  1   1   1
0   -1  0   -1  0   0   0   0   -1  1   1   1
0   -1  0   -1  0   0   0   0   -1  1   1   1
0   -1  0   -1  0   0   0   0   1   1/4 3/4 1/2
0   -1  0   1   0   0   0   0   -1  1/2 1/4 3/4
0   1   0   -1  0   0   0   0   -1  3/4 1/2 1/4
0   -1  0   -1  0   0   0   0   1   1/4 3/4 1/2
0   -1  0   -1  0   0   0   0   1   1/4 3/4 1/2
0   -1  0   -1  0   0   0   0   1   1/4 3/4 1/2
0   -1  0   -1  0   0   0   0   -1  1   1   1
0   -1  0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1/4 1/2 3/4
0   1   0   -1  0   0   0   0   1   1/2 3/4 1/4
0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   -1  3/4 1/4 1/2
0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   -1  3/4 1/4 1/2
0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   -1  3/4 1/4 1/2
0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
0   1   0   -1  0   0   0   0   -1  3/4 1/2 1/4
0   -1  0   1   0   0   0   0   -1  1/2 1/4 3/4
0   -1  0   1   0   0   0   0   -1  1/2 1/4 3/4
0   -1  0   1   0   0   0   0   -1  1/2 1/4 3/4
0   -1  0   1   0   0   0   0   -1  1/2 1/4 3/4
0   -1  0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1/4 1/2 3/4
```

Comment: I just need to the fractions 1/4 1/2 and 3/4 at the end of the line

Comment: So change the ordering. Instead of `0 1 0 "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` and so forth, move the `BASH_REMATCH` values to the end of the list. The order in the output is the same as the order in the echo command, so it's easy to control.

Comment: This code handles `-x` but not just `x`. And it doesn't handle `-y` or `-z`.

Comment: It also requires the expressions to be in the specific order `y`, `x`, `z` -- I suspect his file format isn't that specific.

Comment: Yes this works for the line I provided for input, but I guess I should have shown more for my input file. I appreciate the help, I'll keep trying at this.

Comment: @RobS. It would help if you gave examples of more than one line, it's really hard to extrapolate a whole file format from one example.

Comment: (x,y,z)
(z,x,y)
(y,z,x)
(y+3/4,x+1/4,-z+1/2)
(x+3/4,z+1/4,-y+1/2)
(z+3/4,y+1/4,-x+1/2)
(-x,-y,-z)
(-z,-x,-y)
(-y,-z,-x)
(-y+1/4,-x+3/4,z+1/2)
(-x+1/4,-z+3/4,y+1/2)
(-z+1/4,-y+3/4,x+1/2)
(-x+3/4,-y+1/4,z+1/2)
(z+1/2,-x+3/4,-y+1/4)
(-y+1/4,z+1/2,-x+3/4)
(-y,-x,-z)
(-x+1/2,z+3/4,y+1/4)
(z+1/4,-y+1/2,x+3/4)
(x+1/4,y+3/4,-z+1/2)
(-z+1/2,x+1/4,y+3/4)
(y+3/4,-z+1/2,x+1/4)
(y,x,z)
(x+1/2,-z+1/4,-y+3/4)
(-z+3/4,y+1/2,-x+1/4)
(-x+1/4,y+1/2,-z+3/4)
(-z+3/4,-x+1/4,y+1/2)
(y+1/2,-z+3/4,-x+1/4)
(y+1/4,-x+1/2,z+3/4)
(-x,-z,-y)
all on their own line in input

Comment: @Barmar, yup, I know the limitations -- this is very much a "teach the person to include adequate input/output samples by showing them what happens when they don't" exercise.

Comment: ...though a few hours was probably enough of that. @RobS., see update.

Comment: @RobS. Edit the question, it's difficult to read that in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that may simplify the parsing. Read each line into an array using IFS set to all possible delimiters and characters you don't care about:

```
while IFS=$'\(\)+,' read -ra line; do
    for i in 1 3 5; do
        case "${line[$i]}" in
            x) printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t" 1 0 0 ;;
            y) printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t" 0 1 0 ;;
            z) printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t" 0 0 1 ;;
            -x) printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t" -1 0 0 ;;
            -y) printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t" 0 -1 0 ;;
            -z) printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t" 0 0 -1 ;;
        esac
    done
    for i in 2 4 6; do
        printf "%s\t" "${line[$i]}"
    done
    echo
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: `echo -ne` is better replaced with `printf '%s\t' "${line[$i]}"`. See the [POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), which says (1) that behavior is completely unspecified when `-n` is present; (2) that other options aren't allowed (so handling `-e` as an option, rather than as contents to print, *actively violates the specification*); and (3) that `printf` can be used to simulate all `echo` behavior and is preferred for new code (see the APPLICATION USAGE section).

Comment: Also note that even bash doesn't always support `echo -e` as doing something other than printing `-e` on output -- it switches its behavior over to be standards-compliant when both `posix` and `xpg_echo` flags are set; and either or both of those can be made default via compile-time options.

Comment: Thanks Charles. That explains my occasional portability problems with echo -e. :) I've updated my answer accordingly.