# Reading text file, change order of columns of some lines

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

My input file is of the form:

```
   0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0    0 / 1    0 / 1    0 / 1
   0     1     0 3/4     1     0     0 1/4     0     0    -1 1/2
   0    -1     0 1/4    -1     0     0 3/4     0     0     1 1/2
```

I want to rearrange the order of the lines that have the fraction within them. Currently I have:

```
#!bin/bash
filename="input.txt"
while ((i++)); read -r line; do
  re='[0-9][/][0-9]';
  if [[ $line =~ $re ]]
    then
      echo $line
  fi
done < "$filename"
```

which will echo the second and third line. Is there an awk or sed command I could use to get these two lines to change their order (leaving the first as is) to being

```
$1,$2,$3,$5,$6,$7,$9,$10,$11,$4,$8,$12
```

which would make my file now look like

```
   0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0    0 / 1    0 / 1    0 / 1
   0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0    -1 3/4 1/4 1/2
   0    -1     0    -1     0     0     0     0     1 1/4 3/4 1/2
```

Comment: @anubhava edited

Comment: Hah! [I remember this format!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47214248/1072112)  :-)

Comment: I know, I am just trying to think of a better way of describing my problem and it's probably just making things worse. Starting to think I won't get this figured out and will just have to manually change all lines

Comment: With which character are your columns separated? Do the lines contain a leading separator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily do this with awk, nonetheless I think it is important to define the rules of the game a bit.
Under the following assumptions :

- A fraction is anything of the form : `a/b` or `a / b` or `a/ b`
- If a fraction appears in column 4 or 8, reshuffle the columns.
- you want to keep the formatting correct

With this in mind, you can use the following awk code

```
awk 'BEGIN{format="%4s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%7s%7s%7s\n"}
     { gsub(/[[:blank:]]*\/[[:blank:]]*/,"/",$0); $0=$0 }
     ($4 ~ /\//) || ($8 ~ /\//) { 
        $12=$4" "$8" "$12
        $4=""; $8=""
        $0=$0
     }                                           
     { printf format,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12 }
    ' file.txt
```

This does the following :

- replace all `" / "` or any variant on that by a single `/`
- `$0 = $0` redefines the fields, i.e. in your first two lines, you 
  will move from 18 fields to 12
- if a fraction (i.e. a `/`) appears in field 4 or 8, then redefine field 12, delete field 4 and 8 and do `$0=$0` again.
- print with the correct format.

NOTE: in the above example, the fractions have a different output (no spaces)

The above will give you the following output :

```
   0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0    0/1    0/1    0/1
   0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0    -1    3/4    1/4    1/2
   0    -1     0    -1     0     0     0     0     1    1/4    3/4    1/2
```

If you do not want change your fractions in the first line, then you can do it very easy like this

```
awk 'BEGIN{format="%4s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%6s%7s%7s%7s\n"}
     (NF>12) { print; next }
     { 
        $12=$4" "$8" "$12
        $4=""; $8=""
        $0=$0
        printf format,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12
     }
    ' file.txt
```

Here you assume, that

- if a line has more then 12 fields, just print it
- otherwise, shuffle the columns

This is however less robust as everything depends how the fractions are typed in the 4th,8th and 12th column. I.e. they *must* be typed without spaces. Output will look like :

```
   0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0    0 / 1    0 / 1    0 / 1
   0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0    -1    3/4    1/4    1/2
   0    -1     0    -1     0     0     0     0     1    1/4    3/4    1/2
```

Comment: @RobS. If you have a modern version of gawk you could do inplace replacements (Ref [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-in-place)). Just replace `awk` by `gawk -i inplace`. If your version of awk does not support the inplace, then you can do `awk '...' file.txt > file.new.txt; mv file.new.txt file.txt`. Basically make a new file and rename it.

Comment: The gawk did not work but the simple write the output to a new file and move that file did. Greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

This is better to be done using `awk`:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '/[0-9]\/[0-9]/{print $1,$2,$3,$5,$6,$7,$9,$10,$11,$4,$8,$12; next} 1' file

0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0    0 / 1    0 / 1    0 / 1
0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   -1  3/4 1/4 1/2
0   -1  0   -1  0   0   0   0   1   1/4 3/4 1/2
```

Comment: It did not, fractions remained within the line. Found a solution though.

Comment: Isn't it matching with the expected output shown in question?

Answer (score 0):

@anubhava is a better solution than me. Since I wrote the other code, mind as well.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="input.txt"

awk '
{
for (i=1; i <= NF; i++)
  if ( $(i+1) == "/" || $i == "/" || $(i-1) == "/") {
    printf "MM%sMM",$i" "$(i+1)" "$(i+2)
    i = i+2
  } else if ( match ($i, /^[[:digit:]]\/[[:digit:]]/) ) {
    printf "MM%sMM",$i
  } else {
    printf "MM%sMM",$i
  }
  printf "\n"
}' $filename | sed -e 's/MMMM/MM/g;s/^MM//;s/MM/\t/g'
```